# Android Studio error cannot find symbol method getWindow()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting this error message from the `Android Studio compiler`

```
Error:(160, 50) error: cannot find symbol method getWindow()
```

Here's my code.

```
ProgressBar    spinner;
```

Then elsewhere in my code:

```
    spinner = new ProgressBar(model);
    spinner.setIndeterminate(true);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    homeView.addView(spinner);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = spinner.getWindow().getAttributes();
```

`getWindow()` is a valid call.  This is in an `activity`.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you look at the Spinner documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) there is no method called getWindow().

Comment: "getWindow() is a valid call" - Not on a Spinner object. It's a method of the Activity class. If you want the Activity's window, remove `spinner.`.

Comment: Yeah, it is for the Activity, I just don't understand what he is trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Orkun and Mike M.  You're absolutely right.  I can't figure out where I saw that getWindow was valid.  Perhaps it was getWindowId() and I just missed the Id part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in `Fragment` then call:

```
getActivity().getWindow()
```

If you are in `Activity` then call:

```
getWindow()
```